# How can I download data from an FTP server using python?

Tags: python, noaa

I am trying to download precipitation data from an ftp server. The code that I am using is this, but am still getting errors.

```
import urllib2
urlretrieve("http://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/fews/fewsdata/africa/arc2/geotiff/", "folder link")
```

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Python: download a file over an FTP server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768214/python-download-a-file-over-an-ftp-server). Also, not sure if this question should belong in [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) instead as you are only asking about downloading data :)

Comment: It would help if you said what the errors are.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [**ftp**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) library

example for listing data

```
from ftplib import FTP

host = r'ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/fews/fewsdata/africa/arc2/geotiff'

#for example
ftp.login("anonymous", "ftplib-example-1")
data = []
ftp.dir(data.append)
ftp.quit()
for line in data:
    print line
```